# Python cannot decode json file, although it seems valid

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load and read a json file with this code:

```
try:
    json_data = open('sample3.json')
    data = load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    insert_data(data)
except Exception as e:
    print "Finished with error %s" % (repr(e))
```

This is the Json file:

```
{"competitions":
    [
    {"name":"Premiership","nation":"ENG","id":32711,"matches": 
        [
        {"id":7245940,"when":"28.02.2015 12:45",
            "home_team": {"id":430934, "name":"West Ham"},
            "away_team": {"id":430936, "name":"Crystal Palace"},
            "played":1,
            "play_off":0,
            "round":27
                ,"score":{"t1_score":1,"t2_score":3 },
            "score_ht":{"t1_score":0,"t2_score":1}
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

and this is the error I am getting:
`Finished with error ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)`

I tried file in JSONlint and it says it is valid.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: this is the output of `print repr(json_data.read())`

```
'\xef\xbb\xbf{"competitions":\n    [\n    {"name":"Premiership","nation":"ENG","id":32711,"matches": \n        [\n        {"id":7245940,"when":"28.02.2015 12:45",\n            "home_team": {"id":430934, "name":"West Ham"},\n            "away_team": {"id":430936, "name":"Crystal Palace"},\n            "played":1,\n            "play_off":0,\n            "round":27\n                ,"score":{"t1_score":1,"t2_score":3 },\n            "score_ht":{"t1_score":0,"t2_score":1}\n        }\n        ]\n    }\n    ]\n}\n'
Finished with error ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain you are opening the correct file? What does `print repr(json_data.read())` produce?

Comment: try removing last newline character from json string data

Comment: I can't find a way. I opened the file in vim and it doesn't show anything. `set list` command just shows a `$` at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON file starts with a [UTF-8 BOM (*Byte Order Mark*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) character; JSON doesn't support such a character. It is usually added by Microsoft tools (such as Notepad), to detect encodings, but the characters carry *no meaning* in UTF-8 since there is no byte order variation.

You'll have to skip these bytes directly, as even using the `utf-8-sig` encoding doesn't help here.

You can use [`codecs.BOM_UTF8`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM_UTF8) to detect it:

```
import codecs

with open('sample3.json') as json_data:
    bom_maybe = json_data.read(3)
    if bom_maybe != codecs.BOM_UTF8:
        # no BOM at the start, rewind
        json_data.seek(0)
    data = load(json_data)
insert_data(data)
```

Alternatively, use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to load and decode the data, before passing it to `json.loads()` instead:

```
import io

with io.open('sample3.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_data:
    data = json.loads(json_data.read())
```

Demo:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> import json
>>> open('/tmp/test.json', 'wb').write('\xef\xbb\xbf{"competitions":\n    [\n    {"name":"Premiership","nation":"ENG","id":32711,"matches": \n        [\n        {"id":7245940,"when":"28.02.2015 12:45",\n            "home_team": {"id":430934, "name":"West Ham"},\n            "away_team": {"id":430936, "name":"Crystal Palace"},\n            "played":1,\n            "play_off":0,\n            "round":27\n                ,"score":{"t1_score":1,"t2_score":3 },\n            "score_ht":{"t1_score":0,"t2_score":1}\n        }\n        ]\n    }\n    ]\n}\n')
>>> with open('/tmp/test.json') as json_data:
...     bom_maybe = json_data.read(3)
...     if bom_maybe != codecs.BOM_UTF8:
...         json_data.seek(0)
...     data = json.load(json_data)
... 
>>> data
{u'competitions': [{u'id': 32711, u'matches': [{u'score_ht': {u't2_score': 1, u't1_score': 0}, u'home_team': {u'id': 430934, u'name': u'West Ham'}, u'away_team': {u'id': 430936, u'name': u'Crystal Palace'}, u'played': 1, u'when': u'28.02.2015 12:45', u'round': 27, u'score': {u't2_score': 3, u't1_score': 1}, u'play_off': 0, u'id': 7245940}], u'name': u'Premiership', u'nation': u'ENG'}]}
>>> with io.open('/tmp/test.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_data:
...     data = json.loads(json_data.read())
... 
>>> data
{u'competitions': [{u'id': 32711, u'matches': [{u'score_ht': {u't2_score': 1, u't1_score': 0}, u'home_team': {u'id': 430934, u'name': u'West Ham'}, u'away_team': {u'id': 430936, u'name': u'Crystal Palace'}, u'played': 1, u'when': u'28.02.2015 12:45', u'round': 27, u'score': {u't2_score': 3, u't1_score': 1}, u'play_off': 0, u'id': 7245940}], u'name': u'Premiership', u'nation': u'ENG'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the junk is removed. I still get the same error message.

Comment: @xpanta: how did you remove the bytes? The editor that you are using is probably still including them when saving the file! Instead, detect if the first 3 bytes form the BOM so you can skip them.

Comment: @xpanta, the BOM characters are there in your message as well "\xef\xbb\xbf", i did not notice them myself

Comment: @NikosM.: I asked the OP to add the output of `repr(json_data.read())` to their question, because I suspected a BOM might be involved.